# iOS: TPKeyboardAvoiding - Cursor does not advance to the next parallel-height UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, tpkeyboardavoiding

I am using TPKeyboardAvoiding in my current app project. I have this peculiar problem where I have 3 text fields on the same height level (y-position). When I click "Next", the cursor correctly jumps from the 1st text field to the 2nd. But if I click "Next" again, the cursor does not jump to the 3rd field. Instead it jumps back to the 1st field. And it just keep on jumping back to the 1st field, whenever I wanna jump from the 2nd field to the 3rd field.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: do you added  3rd textfield.delegate = self;  in your code ..

Comment: TPKeyboardAvoiding would do that in the background for me. And all have been working well so far for UITextfields that have different y-position. For example, in my case above, as soon as I put the 3 fields on a descending y-position, the cursor jumps correctly. Strange.

Comment: can you include some code snippet.

Comment: I have attached here the TPKeyboardAvoiding library link: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: There's actually no codes on my side. I just need to import the library files to my project, embed my view in a scrollview, and change the scrollview to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView class will do. Everything will work accordingly

Comment: ok .. then can you insure that 3rd textfield is added to the scrollview correctly .

Comment: I'm sure it is, cause simply by changing the height of the 2nd field to be lower by one pixel to the 1st filed, and the 3rd field lower by one pixel to the 2nd field, it all work perfectly well. The cursors jumps from the 1st to the 2nd and to the 3rd and then finally the keyboard resigns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75904/discussion-between-vais-and-marcus).

Comment: if it possible can u share some screen shots of your xib or storyboard.